# Efficiency of HashTable and Collections.synchronized(HashMap)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was going to implement some code which needs a synchronized data structure.  I came up with `HashTable` and `Collections.synchronized(HashMap)`.  I wouldn't be needing `ConcurrentHashMap` for this.  I was wondering which one of the two would be better.

PS :  I will be calling a lot of getter of this object and they would not be at the same time.  So their is no problem with concurrency issue also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is much more scaleable: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/concurrenthashmap_scalability.shtml

`HashTable` and `Collections.synchronized(HashMap)` provide with the same performance, but they are *conditionally* thread-safe (i.e. they are not fully thread-safe)

If there are a lot read operations, I would recommend to wrap it with read-write locks:

```
public class MyHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
     private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        final Lock w = lock.writeLock();
        w.lock();
        try {
            return super.put(key, value);
        } finally {
            w.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        final Lock r = lock.readLock();
        r.lock();
        try {
            return super.get(key);
        } finally {
            r.unlock();
        }
    }
    .... // the same approach distinguishing read and write operations

}
```

UPDATE:

> I will be calling a lot of getter of this object and they would not be at the same time

It doesn't guarantee that you don't need synchronization.

Comment: I am not looking for anything which is thread-safe because they will be accessed only by an admin always . ConcurrentHashMap is bulky compared to that of the HashMap and HashTable.  I don't the exact size but its was some like this for empty concurrenthashmap - 170  and hashtable - 150

Comment: Do you access the map in a web-application? If it's accessed from different threads (which is the case for any server side) - then it should be thread-safe, even if only one user accesses it.

Comment: The functionality of it being used is a little complex to explain.  But I am confident that there wont be any thread issues with it.

Comment: Then use plain HashMap. But note, than concurrency issues is not only when an object is accessed at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to acquire a lock on the whole map for some reason (unlikely) you should go for `ConcurrentHashMap` which gives much better scalability.

`HashTable` and the synchronized wrapper (`Collections.synchronized(HashMap)`) use one lock whereas `ConcurrentHashMap` partitions the map in 16 segments by default, each having its own lock, which gives much better concurrent access.

Comment: Yea I lock will that structure once I set it

Answer (score 0):

Although HashTable is thread-safe but it doesn't guarantee that it make your whole code thread-safe.HashTable also has some performance issue. So you should use HashMap but you have to manage all thread-safety yourself.